# How can I use backbone.js's polymorphism, especially super's attributes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, polymorphism

I am trying to make super-class(MyShape) and sub-class(MyTriangle, MyRectangle). I already searched some backbone.js's polymorphism concept...but have no idea on this problem.

I hava a .json file like below

```
[
{
    "type": "rect",
    "x": 10,
    "y": 10,
    "w": 100,
    "h": 100,
    "color": "red"
},
{
    "type": "arc",
    "x": 210,
    "y": 20,
    "w": 200,
    "h": 150,
    "color": "blue"
}
]
```

And I made inheritance structure using backbone.js like below.

```
    var MyShape = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            color : '',
            src : '',
        }
    });

    var MyRectangle = MyShape.extend({
        defaults : {
            x : 0,
            y : 0
        }
    });

    var MyTriangle = MyShape.extend({
        defaults : {
            x : -10,
            y : -10
        }
    });

    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : MyShape,
    });
```

As you can see above, the super class(MyShape) has color and src attributes. I hava a problem because of this. If I make MyTriangle instance I think I cannot use src or color attributes on that object.

Q.If I want to make a code like below(this example is Java Based), how should I code it?

```
    MyShape myShape = null;
    if (type.equals("rect")) {
        myShape = new MyRectangle(x, y, w, h);
    } else if (type.equals("arc")) {
        myShape = new MyArc(x, y, w, h);
    } else if (type.equals("triangle")) {
        myShape = new MyTriangle(x, y, w, h);
    } else {
        return null;
    }


    // option - src or color
    if (jsonObject.has("src")) {
        myShape.setImg(jsonObject.get("src").toString());
    } else if (jsonObject.has("color")) {
        myShape.setColor(jsonObject.get("color").toString);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

I have to maintain this structure(MyShape, MyTriangle, MyRectangle).

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you ask for clarification of Backbone's polymorphism while directly limiting the answers to show how to do the polymorphism using your code?

Comment: *"If I make MyTriangle instance I think I cannot use src or color attributes on that object.*" - why do you think so..? what exactly do you mean by *use*??

Comment: If I do "var myshape = new MyTriangle();" then the type of myshpe is of course MyTriangle. That means, I cannot set the src or color attribute which is in the super class(MyShape). What I want to do is set the src or img while having their Shape Identity(MyTriangle or MyRectangle). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `default` from parent class, you need to extend the defaults of parent class.

So, for example ([source](http://www.shakedos.com/2012/Jun/23/extending-backbone-model-while-keeping-defaults-parent-init-method.html))

```
var MyRectangle = defaults : _.extend({}, MyShape.prototype.defaults, {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
     })
});
```

To use polymorphic models in backbone collection ([source](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model), [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527328/backbone-collection-of-polymorphic-models))

> A collection can also contain polymorphic models by overriding this property with a constructor that returns a model.

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   model: function(attrs, options) {
     if (condition) {
      return new PublicDocument(attrs, options);
    } else {
    return new PrivateDocument(attrs, options);
    }
  }
});
```

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/je5dq5wc/10/) putting it all together

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps me.

Comment: In the 42-line, What is the second parameter, 'options' tough?

Comment: Simply put `options` are optional arguments which can be passed as configuring function, contextual info (like which model or collection it belongs to) or additional data. For e.g. you can pass `comparator` as options. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997714/what-is-options-in-backbone-js) will  be helpful. See the default options for collection [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-102)

Comment: @JinnySong please accept your answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Yes, I solved it. You were so helpful. Thanks a lot~ :)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this.~